# How to convert property list from XML to JSON?

Tags: xml, json, sublimetext2

Sublime Text 2 uses plist to define language syntax , just like TextMate.
 But as the docs says, people write JSON to make plugins then convert it to plist rather than use YAML or JSON directly.
And I look through some plgins, most of them just provide `.tmLanguage` file in its Github repo. Do they write XML directly?

Anyway once I want to learn from others' code I have to read XML, or I have to convert plist to JSON.
There is a package of Sublime does that previously.
https://github.com/facelessuser/PlistJsonConverter
But it requires python2.6 which made me confused because no both my Arch and Ubuntu 12.10 there's I can't find python2.6. It's 2.7.

Is there any method I can convert plist to JSON please?

Comment: @John My laptop runs Archlinux and there's another Ubuntu desktop I can use.

Comment: Actually nevermind, `plistlib` is available on all platforms as of 2.6.  Have you looked into that?

Comment: I didn't know that. Sounds not good. Is there any other tools parsing plist then?

Comment: I tried to install python 2.6 on my laptop before. But coundn't find the right package. 2.7.3 is on my OS. I'm unfamiliar about downgrading packages. And python is such a common used package. I don't like to reinstall it.

Comment: You don't seem to understand. I said Python 2.6 **or greater**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20722/discussion-between-jiyinyiyong-and-john)

Answer (score 1):

Using `plistlib` and Python 2.6 or greater:

```
import json
import plistlib

plist = open(path)
plist_object = readPlist(plist)

json_serialized = json.dumps(plist_object)
```

Comment: Python 3.6.0. Getting error `NameError: name 'readPlist' is not defined`